# PHP Within Google Maps API V3

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having a puzzling little problem with the Google Maps API which has had me tearing my hair out. The following code

```
<?php
$anim='images/animation.gif';
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['anim']==1) {
$anim='images/transparent.png';
}

//Select database
require_once('../Connections/MySQL_extranet.php');
mysql_select_db($database_MySQL_extranet, $MySQL_extranet);

// Get the hid which is passed from previous page
if (isset($_REQUEST['hid'])) {
    $hid=$_REQUEST['hid'];
}

//MySQL query to select location details
$query_location = "SELECT hotel, lat, lng, zoomair, sp_lat, sp_lng FROM ex_hotel WHERE hid = '$hid'";
$location = mysql_query($query_location, $MySQL_extranet) or die(mysql_error());
$row_location = mysql_fetch_assoc($location);

//Set the session variable to pass the hotel name
$_SESSION['hotel'] = $row_location['hotel'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 7)|!(IE)]><!--> <html> <!--<![endif]-->
<!--Dump the above when IE7 users go below 2% -->
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Little Hotels - Directions to <?php echo $row_location['hotel'];?></title>
<meta name="description" content="Little Hotels provides accurate directions to hotels from any starting point you choose.">
<meta name="keywords" content="hotel directions, google maps, Little Hotels, driving directions, directions to <?php echo $row_location['hotel'];?>">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" >
<?php 
$full_url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$canonical_url = strtok($full_url,'?');
echo '<link rel="canonical" href="' . $canonical_url . '" >'; 
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/littlehotels.css" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
#content{padding: 70px 5px 0; width: 100%;}
#mapcontainer{float:left; display:block;}
#mapCanvas {width: 600px; height: 400px;}

#markerStatus {height: 0px;}
#info {height: 0px;}
#infoPanel {margin-left: 620px; margin-right:10px; display:block;}
#infoPanel div {margin-bottom: 5px;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var lat = <?php echo $row_location['lat'];?>;
    var lng = <?php echo $row_location['lng'];?>;
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

function geocodePosition(pos) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    latLng: pos
  }, function(responses) {
    if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
      updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
    } else {
      updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
    }
  });
}

function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
  document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
}

function updateMarkerPosition(startpoint) {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
    startpoint.lat(),
    startpoint.lng()
  ].join(', ');
  }

function nextPage() {
  saddress = document.getElementById('info').innerHTML;
location='directions_detail.php?saddr='+saddress+'&daddr='+latlng;
}

function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
  document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
}

function initialize() {
    var zoom = <?php echo $row_location['zoomair'];?>;
    var sp_lat = <?php echo $row_location['sp_lat'];?>;
    var sp_lng = <?php echo $row_location['sp_lng'];?>;
    var startpoint = new google.maps.LatLng(sp_lat, sp_lng);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
    zoom: zoom,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    streetViewControl: false,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
    }
  });

var destimage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/images/hotel_icon.gif',
      new google.maps.Size(32, 37),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(16, 35));
var destshadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/images/hotelshadow.png',
      new google.maps.Size(51, 37),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(16, 35));
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  icon: destimage,
  shadow: destshadow,
  map: map,
  position: latlng
});

var startimage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
  '/images/start_icon.png',
      new google.maps.Size(59, 37),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(29, 35));
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: startpoint,
    title: 'If necessary, drag this to a different start point',
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    icon: startimage
  });

  // Update current position info.
  updateMarkerPosition(startpoint);
  geocodePosition(startpoint);

  // Add dragging event listeners.
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
    updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
    updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');
    updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
    geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
  });
}

// Onload handler to fire off the app.
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
<div id="wrapper">
<a href="http://www.littlehotels.co.uk"><img src="images/transparent.png" width="266" height="122" border="0" alt="Little Hotels"></a>
<img src="<?php echo $anim ?>" alt="Little Hotels logo" width="93" height="117" align="top">
<img src="images/header/directions.png" alt="Little Hotels" width="364" height="88">
<div id="container">
<?php include("includes/topnavbar.html"); ?>
<div id="breadcrumb">
<div class="bc-link" style="width:200px"><a href="../carhire.php" target="_blank">Car Hire at competitive rates</a></div>
<div class="bc-link"><a href="flights.php" target="_blank">Flights</a></div>
<div class="bc-link"><a href="ferries.php" target="_blank">Ferries</a></div>
<div class="bc-link"><a href="airportparking.php" target="_blank">Airport Parking</a></div>
<div class="bc-link"><a href="airporthotels.php" target="_blank">Airport Hotels</a></div>
<div class="bc-link" style="width:200px"><a href="travelinsurance.php" target="_blank">Travel Insurance</a></div>
<div class="bc-link" style="width:200px" align="right"><a href="wp/" target="_blank">News and Special Offers</a></div>
</div>
  <div id="content">
<div id="mapcontainer">
<table border=1 bordercolor="#666666">
      <tr>
        <td>
  <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="infoPanel">
<h2>Driving Directions to <?php echo $row_location['hotel'];?> </h2>
<!-- Following two lines must be kept in, even though not visible. Also corresponding lines in Style -->
    <div id="markerStatus" style="visibility:hidden;"><i>Click and drag the marker.</i></div>
    <div id="info" style="visibility:hidden;"></div>
    <b>Start Point:</b>
    <div id="address"></div>
    <br><b>Destination:</b><br>
    <div><?php echo $row_location['hotel'];?></div>
<br>
To select a different starting point, just drag the start icon to the required location (zoom in if necessary for better precision).<br>
<br>
<button onclick="nextPage()">Get Directions</button>
<br>
<span class="verdana"><br>

</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php 
$_SESSION['anim']=1;
?>
```

creates a satisfactory page (http://new.littlehotels.co.uk/directions_hotel.php?hid=colorado) but I want to add a couple of refinements. These changes need me to create a javascript variable from a piece of MySQL data.

Therefore I want to create a line something like this:

```
var hotelname = <?php echo $row_location['hotel'];?>;
```

That shouldn't be too hard as I already have several similar lines in the working code. However, this new line breaks the page every time, no matter what variations I try. When I add that line in, the page displays but without the map and without the name of the Start Point on the righthand side.

Is it me?????????????

Comment: It's probably a JavaScript syntax error. Check the console. What's the value of `$row_location['hotel']`?

Comment: You have an SQL injection bug in your code:

`$query_location = "SELECT hotel, lat, lng, zoomair, sp_lat, sp_lng FROM ex_hotel WHERE hid = '$hid'";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you are outputting a string from `$row_location['hotel']` in that case you need to wrap in quotes to tell javascript its not a variable but a string value.

thus:

```
var hotelname = "<?php echo $row_location['hotel'];?>";
```

To check if the above hypothesis is true check your console and you will see the following error:

```
ReferenceError: <value returned by $raw_location['hotel']> is not defined
```

Comment: You guessed right! That was exactly the problem and it's now working beautifully. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Like this one can pass variables to JS and it prevents the PHP interpreter from complaining about any missing indexes, just in case (it depends how error reporting is set in php.ini), for example:

```
var hotelname = "<?php echo(isset($row_location['hotel']) ? $row_location['hotel'] :''); ?>";
console.info(hotelname);
```

The surrounding quotes are the difference, like this $row_location['hotel'] gets casted to string in JavaScript.

... what does this code return, you even get any result?

```
while ($row_location = mysql_fetch_assoc($location)) {
   echo '<pre>'.print_r($row_location,true).'</pre>';
}
```